# Flutter move the card with an animation to the discard pile

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm new to Flutter, I'm creating a card game, how can I move the card "cardImage" (I'll add more cards later, to represent the deck) to the discard pile with a smooth animation?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue.shade700)),
    home: CardHomeView(),
  ));
}

class CardHomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardHomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CardHomeView> createState() => _CardHomeViewState();
}

class _CardHomeViewState extends State<CardHomeView> {
  Image cardImage =
      Image.asset('assets/verse.png', height: 200); 
  List<Image> cardStack = [];
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 300, 
            child: Stack(
              children: List.generate(
                cardStack.length,
                (index) {
                  final image = cardStack[index];
                  return AnimatedPositioned(
                    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                    left: index * 10,

                    child: image,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                cardStack.add(cardImage);
              });
            },
            child: cardImage,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In another code, I tried to use a SlideTransition with an animation for each card, they all go to the same position (to the discard pile), but all the cards stay on top of each other in the deck, if I use Positioned(left : cards.indexOf(card) * 35, the cards are not on top of each other, but in the final position of the animation, they are also separated, just like in the deck

```
Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: cards.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                final index = entry.key;
                final card = entry.value;
                final imageName = getCardImageName(card);

                return Positioned(
                    child: SlideTransition(
                  position: cardControllers[index].drive(_animation),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          cardControllers[index].forward();
                        });
                      },
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/uno_images/$imageName',
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50,
                      )),
                ));
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
```